# Condition for curve to be an extremal does not depend on the choice of coordinate system

Tags: multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations

I am reading V.Arnold book "Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics" and on page 59 he mentions that "the condition for a curve $\gamma$ to be an extremal of a functional does not depend on the choice of coordinate system". Unfortunately, he does not give a proof for that and does not give a hint for how one could prove it.

Can you please help me with this problem?

Comment: This is because the functional depends only on (possibly the parameter and) the curve and its (various order) tangent vectors, not any ambient coordinates. That is, the functional involves just the geometry of the curve.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your comment! I think I intuitively understand you, but unfortunately, I am not sure if I am able to give a proof for this statement. Can you please help me with that?